# How do I get the local port my WCF service runs on?

Tags: .net, wcf, port

I'm using multiple self-hosted WCF services on the same machine. I need to open each of them on a different port (obviously), so I used "net:tcp://localhost:0" as address since I figured it would assign a free port this way.

Now I need to know which port was assigned actually. This code runs on the server, so I need the *local* port. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563393/how-can-i-get-the-port-that-a-wcf-service-is-listening-on

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the listening address/port of a WCF service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207348/how-can-i-get-the-listening-address-port-of-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that works, even though it is a bit dirty. Instead of automatically assigning a port, a free port is explicitly requested and used to create the service:

```
Address = "net.tcp://localhost:" + FindFreeTcpPort ();

private static int FindFreeTcpPort ()
{
    TcpListener l = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Parse ("127.0.0.1"), 0);
    l.Start ();
    int port = ((IPEndPoint) l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
    l.Stop ();
    return port;
}
```

(the method code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138043/find-the-next-tcp-port-in-net/150974#150974))

Comment: Since I got no new responses I'll accept this solution even though I don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OperationContext.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Port` to know the port used in the call to a service

Comment: Is there a way to do it outside the service itself (in the console host code)? I don't have an OperationContext there.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need another place to store all service's ports to read them from outside the server. If it's another service, then it needs a constant port. It also can be a xml file over http or something modified on each of service's startup.

More on [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx)

Comment: I'm in .net 3.5, WCF Discovery is not available sadly.