# Get port number from ServiceHost

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, port

I'm creating a WCF `ServiceHost` with port 0 in order to get a dynamically assigned port:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:0/abc"));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyInterface), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "net.tcp://localhost:0/abc");
```

How do I get the port number assigned?

I tried:

```
host.ChannelDispatchers[0].Listener.Uri.Port
```

but it just returns 0 which is presumably wrong.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467651/how-do-i-get-the-local-port-my-wcf-service-runs-on

Comment: It suggests using `OperationContext.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Port`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured it out. You need to make sure the listen URI behavior is set to unique and also open it. By default it is set to explicit.

I made a bogus service class that contained the following service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyClass
{
   [OperationContract]
   public string Test()
   {
      return "test";
   }
}
```

And added the corresponding test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestMyClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public string TestPortIsNotZero(){
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass), 
            new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:0/abc"));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyClass), 
            new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "net.tcp://localhost:0/abc");
        //had to set the listen uri behavior to unique
        endpoint.ListenUriMode = ListenUriMode.Unique;
        //in addition open the host
        host.Open();

        foreach (var cd in host.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
           //prints out the port number in the dynamic range
           Debug.WriteLine(cd.Listener.Uri.Port);
           Assert.IsTrue(cd.Listener.Uri.Port >= 0); 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This works. But according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.listenurimode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if port sharing is on - it will add a guid to the uri. There _should_ be a way to get the port without this as it doesn't seem to be related.