# Automatically set port number at client side while using wcf duplex binding

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdualhttpbinding

I have implemented wcf service with duplex binding and it is working fine.
What I have done at client side is I have configured ClientBaseAddress in config file. Default port i.e. 80 which I want my application to automatically use available port.

So my question, is there any way where I can automatically set the available free port?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking but as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563393/how-can-i-get-the-port-that-a-wcf-service-is-listening-on) answer, you can set the port to '0' and this will cause WCF to pick the next available free port. However, this seems to be a random port and not necessarily port 80. It's unclear to me whether you specifically want port 80.

Using this method will cause a problem on your client. They will not know which port to talk over. There is a feature in WCF called [WCF Discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in which a client 'discovers' the location of the service over a network.